# Take many elements by pluck Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function getPackage($type)
{
    $sale = Tour::where('id_package',$type)->get();
    $pack = Package::where('id',$sale->pluck('id_package'))->get();
    $loca = Location::where('id','=',$sale->pluck('id_location'))->get();
    return view('page.package',compact('pack','loca','sale'));
}
```

When i use dd($sale->pluck('id_location'), i can get two element but when I assign $loca to only one, and when I use whereIn('id',$sale->pluck('id_location') I can get two element but does not match the id tour @@

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `where()` with a collection, use `whereIn()` using this syntax:

```
$sale = Tour::where('id_package', $type)->get();
$pack = Package::whereIn('id', $sale->pluck('id_package'))->get();
$loca = Location::whereIn('id', $sale->pluck('id_location'))->get();
```

Also, if you want to load `Tours` with related packages and locations, you should define relationships and [use eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
public function getPackage($type)
{
    $sale = Tour::where('id_package', $type)->with(['location', 'package'])->get();
    return view('page.package', compact('sale'));
}
```

Comment: @QuanNguyen yes, they do not match because you're loading many tours. Your code will load locations for many tours (many `id_location` values). If you want to load location and package related to each tour, use eager loading as I've shown in my answer.